# Questions with no good answers?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

What if I ask a question, and get no good answers. This is hurting my accept ratio... but not because I'm too lazy to mark one as correct, just no one has posted a reasonable answer. Maybe it's not a terribly important question, so I don't want to start a bounty... what can we do? Can we at least flag the question as "given up" or something?

Answer (score 7):

see

[Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions)

Have you really invested the effort into getting your questions answered?

Comment: Sometimes no, and that's my point. It might be a minor problem I'm having with one of the many projects I'm working on, and it's just not a high priority. In fact, I might give up on the project before the question gets answered thus making it not really relevant (to me, anyways). I don't think it's worth deleting though, because it might be valuable to someone else, or to myself again, if I ever take up that project again.

Answer (score 5):

No one expects you to maintain a 100% accept rate.  If you have a few questions that didn't generate a good answer, it's not that big of deal.

From [Jeff's announcement of acceptance rate](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/):

> It is considered good manners to accept answers on your questions, eventually, but **accepting answers is not required**. I personally consider anything at 70% or over quite good, meaning you accept answers on 7 out of 10 questions that you ask. **There are certainly cases where you don’t get an answer you like, or the question is inherently unanswerable**.

Answer (score 2):

Community Wiki questions don't seem to affect your accept ratio, at least from what I've seen on a question I asked that I *started* as CW.  Maybe marking as CW will stop it from being counted in your accept ratio?